# Average from inner array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

my task is to calculate average value from an array.

```
$arrayToTest = [[[1], 1], [[1,3,5,7], 4], [[2,5,4,1,2,3], 2.8],
    [[-1,-1,-1,-1,-1], -1], [[4,23,84,12,76,34,-7,-23], 25.375]];
```

From inner array, so for `example [1,3,5,7]` and expected value is 4.
I have to use a function, I tried this:

```
function arrayAverage ($arrayToTest)
{
   foreach($arrayToTest as $case)
      foreach ($case as $item)
      {
         $arraySum = array_sum($item);
         $arrayCount = array_count_values($item);
         $average = $arraySum / $arrayCount;
         return $average;
      }
}
```

but it does not work. I feel I'm doing something wrong with calling the inner array.

Comment: You should not `return`, it will end the function immediately without it having done all its work. What do you really need? Do you need to verify that each expected value is correct? Or do you want to ignore that information? What should be the output, as you will have many averages? An array?

Comment: the average is already there, what is there to calculate?

Comment: inner array is  `[1,3,5,7], 4]` or `[1,3,5,7]]` ?write your example  array correctly

Comment: your code will work if you change `$case` to `$case[0]` btw

Comment: Could you provide what the input array is, and then what the expected output array would look like?

Comment: @trincot Yes, I need to verify if what I calculate is correct against the value I have given (as a [1] in each array). but that part shouldn't be a problem for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Comment:

- I assume that you wish to calculate the average values of the **innermost arrays**.
- The solution below returns the **average of each array** - not the **average of all arrays**. But - of course you easily could calculate the average of all arrays.
- Therefore the function *arrayAverage(…)* **returns an array of average values** instead of the average value of (only) the last array.
- I declared the input array (*arrayToTest*) explicitely, for the reason that one can better see the array structure (array of arrays and scalars) like this.

### Code:

```
<?php

$arrayToTest = array (
    array(
        array(1),
        1
    ), 
    array(
        array(1,3,5,7), 
        4
    ),
    array(
        array(2,5,4,1,2,3),
        2.8
    ),
    array(
        array(-1,-1,-1,-1,-1), 
        -1
    ),
    array(
        array(4,23,84,12,76,34,-7,-23),
        25.375
    )
);

echo '<pre>'; print_r($arrayToTest); echo '</pre>';
$average = arrayAvarage ($arrayToTest);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($average); echo '</pre>';

function arrayAvarage ($arrayToTest) {
    $result = array();
    foreach($arrayToTest as $case) {
        foreach ($case as $items) {
            if (!is_array($items)) continue;  
            $result[] = array_sum($items) / count($items);
        }
    }  
    return $result;
}

?>
```

### Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 2.8333333333333
    [3] => -1
    [4] => 25.375
)
```

Answer (score 0):

if your array contains internal arrays in the index 0, you can do this by:

```
function arrayAvarage ($arrayToTest)
{
   $out_put_arr = array();
   foreach($arrayToTest as $case)
      {
         $arraySum = array_sum($case[0]);
         $arrayCount = array_count_values($case[0]);
         $avarage = $arraySum / $arrayCount;
         $out_put_arr[]= $avarage;
      }
 return $out_put_arr;
}
```

so the loop for the main array, each item in the main array will give you array, and int $case[0] = `[1,3,5,7]`  and $case[1] = `4`, also you shouldn't return in for loop because this will return the first average only. so you can declare new array to fill with all averages.

Answer (score 0):

```
function average($array){
  return array_sum($array) / count($array);
}

foreach($arrayToTest as $array){
  echo "Average: " . average($array[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the first element of the *$case* array, which is the actual place where the array with values is situated. Note that you can also use the *array_sum* function.

Also, you should not `return` just like that, because that will interrupt the function from doing anything more. So, only `return` when you really want to do that.

As you already have expected values, I see no reason why your function should return those averages again. Instead it could verify the correctness of these expected values, and return the index of the array when that comparison fails.

```
function arrayAverage ($arrayToTest)
{
    foreach($arrayToTest as $index => $case) {
        $average = array_sum($case[0]) / count($case[0]);
        if ($average !== $case[1]) {
            return $index; // not expected value
        }
    }
    return false; // all averages are equal to expected value
}
```

So, the above function will return *FALSE* when all averages are as expected. Otherwise it will return the index of the first mismatch.